# Best way to mount tv on cavity wall?

Tags: mounting, television

I have a TV that is 65" and 24Kg and I am wanting to mount onto my wall.

My wall appears to be stud & plasterboard (potentially dot & dab?) with breeze block behind - cavity between, of course.

I have seen that a multitude of opinions on how to go about this, so I'm curious on the various options.

**Note:** I haven't yet checked where the studs are, but I imagine that the place where I want the mount to go will be in a void.

I have seen that there are a plethora of fixings designed for plasterboard mounting:

1. Self tapping steel cavity plug - rated for 10Kg each

[image]

2. GripIt anchors - Rated for 100kg (or so it says?)

[image]

3. Spring toggle - Unkown rating

[image]

4. Another wall toggle - unknown rating

[image]

5. Fischer's own zip and snap style fixing - Rated for 20Kg/fixing

[image]

**Note:** The wall bracket I have ordered (HAMA brand) does actually come with all of its own fixings and those included at the more conventional Fischer wall fixings that I have previously used to hand curtains and other less heavy items:

[image]

If they are supplied with the product, they should be sufficient?

**OR.....**

Should I drill deeper, into the breeze block and use a fixing into that instead?

Comment: Anchors might be good enough(?), but for a non cheap TV/picture/mirror I would like to mount to studs directly or screw plywood/wood to studs to cover the voids and mount to that.

Answer (score 3):

> My wall appears to be stud & plasterboard

Figure out if it has studs or not. If it has wooden studs, you can use either a mounting bracket into at least two studs (many have *lots* of mounting holes so that you can position it over studs easily but still be in the desired location) or mount a sheet of plywood into at least two studs and then attach the mounting bracket to the plywood. Either of these methods will be more secure than just about any toggle/anchor/etc. method.

Comment: Why "mount a sheet of plywood into at least two studs"? I think if 3/4" plywood is mounted to the wall approximately centered over one stud, then two sufficiently strong screws into the one stud would be enough, along with two anchors into the voids, one on either side of the stud.. And possibly one anchor Into a void would suffice.

Comment: That should be OK, but I feel much safer mounting it to two studs.